# How to get s3 cloudfront image url from wordpress datababse

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-s3

WordPress image uploaded to s3 amazon contain a random number example image is

```
 `https://randserver.cloudfront.net/articles/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/1517137892/image.jpg`
```

how can I get this number from DB? is it stored in a database? how can I get this image url if I am getting a WordPress post outside WordPress.
The path stored in post table is the normal path like

```
https://www.myserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/crazy-nights-dubai-lucky-voice-candypants.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

This number is stored in wp_postmeta table.
You can find the record with "amazonS3_info" value of "meta_key" attribute.